# Matplotlib axis label move scientific exponent into same line

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, errorbar

I am currently producing a plot which on the x-axis ranges from 0 to 1.3e7. I am plotting this as follows:

```
plt.errorbar(num_vertices,sampled_ave_path_average,yerr=sampled_ave_path_stdev,fmt='.',markersize='1',capsize=2,capthick=2)
plt.xlabel('Number of vertices')
plt.ylabel('Average shortest path length')
plt.xlim(0,1.3*10**7)
plt.savefig('path_length_vs_N.eps', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.savefig('path_length_vs_N.png', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.close()
```

This produces a plot where the x-axis tick labels are in scientific notation which is what I would like. I was however wondering whether it is possible to move the `1e7` (circled in red below) onto the same line as the other labels? (I realise this could cause confusion about the exponents of the other values.)

[image: output of plot routine showing location of scientific exponent marker]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you may look at the following questions:

- [How to move the y axis scale factor to the position next to the y axis label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760763/how-to-move-the-y-axis-scale-factor-to-the-position-next-to-the-y-axis-label)
- [Colorbar offsetText (scientific base multiplier) move from top to bottom of colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43718275/colorbar-offsettext-scientific-base-multiplier-move-from-top-to-bottom-of-colo)

The first one may be a possible alternative (because you mention that the envisioned solution "might cause confusion about the exponents"). The second might point a way to a possible solution although it is about using a colorbar.

So in order to change the position of the offset text to be in line with the xtick labels, the following would be a way to go.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import types

x = np.linspace(1e7, 9e7)
y = 1-np.exp(-np.linspace(0,5))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)


pad = plt.rcParams["xtick.major.size"] + plt.rcParams["xtick.major.pad"]
def bottom_offset(self, bboxes, bboxes2):
    bottom = self.axes.bbox.ymin
    self.offsetText.set(va="top", ha="left") 
    oy = bottom - pad * self.figure.dpi / 72.0
    self.offsetText.set_position((1, oy))

ax.xaxis._update_offset_text_position = types.MethodType(bottom_offset, ax.xaxis)

plt.show()
```

[image]