# Offset text position in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, axis-labels, formatter, yaxis

I would like to move the offset text in matplotlib from above the y-axis to besides the y-axis. The following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([0,1],[0,1e-6],'o-')
ax.yaxis.set_offset_position('left')
ax.set_xlabel('$x$')
ax.set_ylabel('$y$')
plt.show()
```

results in this figure:
[image: original figure]

I am aware of this command

```
ax.yaxis.set_offset_position('left')
```

However, it only accepts an option of "left" or "right". Does anyone know how to move the offset text to the position as in the following figure?
[image: desired figure]

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760763/how-to-move-the-y-axis-scale-factor-to-the-position-next-to-the-y-axis-label, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43718275/colorbar-offsettext-scientific-base-multiplier-move-from-top-to-bottom-of-colo

Comment: Also relevant: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4476